# Use of "Afghani" as an adjective

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

So we know that the noun ["Afghan" is preferred over "Afghani"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27625/which-term-is-correct-afghan-or-afghani) when it comes to describing the people of Afghanistan, but what's the scoop for using it as an adjective?  For example, is saying an "Afghani carpet" incorrect, offensive, both or neither, as opposed to an "Afghan carpet"?

Context: [A rather lively debate on Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/24164/1893) about whether using the term "Afghani passport" in a newspaper article is a mark of cluelessness.

Comment: Any proper noun can be used as an adjective in English. If you're interested in whether the form _Afghani_ is offensive, you'd do better asking an English-speaking Afghan and listening to what they tell you. They are, after all, the people whom you are concerned about offending, right? Why would anyone but an Afghan take offense about uses of the word _Afghani_ in English?

Comment: Note that whatever the correct words are in English or Dari, without knowing the cultural situation, it would be natural to use 'Afghan' as a noun or adjective, but also not strange to use 'Afghani' for a person (on analogy with other Middle Eastern toponyms like Omani, Iraqi, Kuwaiti). But the real answer should be what people from Afghanistan are comfortable with in English.

Comment: I wonder if this is a little like the word Scotch which at one time was to Scotland as Dutch  is to Holland, but now refers only to whisky, the word Scottish having superseded it for all other purposes.,

Comment: The question you link to ('"Afghan is preferred over "Afghani"') does not seem at all decisive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *Afghan* is both the noun (for people and things) and the 
adjective in Dari (the variety of Persian used in Afghanistan. The term
*afghani* is a separate noun, referring to a small unit of currency.

We have evidence in English from usage much earlier than the events of
post-1978 showing *Afghan* as both a noun and an adjective, e.g. Afghan
carpet, Afghan hound, and a knitted or crocheted Afghan (lap blanket),
thanks to contacts between the Raj (British colonists of the Subcontinent)
and Afghans.

I am frustrated when I hear academics using *afghani* as a noun
(other than to mention the coin) and adjective with their students,
thus perpetrating the error.

Answer (score 4):

I had cultural sensitivity training for work in Afghanistan. I was taught that Afghan is the word you are looking for. It describes a person or thing from Afghanistan. Afghani is the money.

---

The Afghan rug cost me 500 Afghani.

Answer (score 1):

The CIA world factbook gives [Afghan](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/af.html).
There's a Slate article [here](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/chatterbox/2001/10/more_on_afghani.html) that gives more on the topic. Afghan is definitely the correct word.

Comment: Both the CIA world factbook are about calling people "Afghanis", but I'm asking about using it as an adjective, eg. "Afghani passport".

Answer (score 0):

Several decent sites I have found suggest that, for example, "an Afghan family" is widely preferred to "an Afghani family." But 1) I don't use this word much, and 2) this usage seems contrary to other terms such as Hindustani or Uzbekistani. So pardon me if I have to stop and think.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. We are looking for longer answers that include references and citations. If you need assistance in framing an answer, please visit our [Help Page on "How to write an answer"](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)